# Fill a div gradually when going on another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to set up a menu that changes color gradually depending on its position on the various div a site.
We begin with a blue box on white div , and when you arrive on the second black div , gradually moving the box white.

But if the box remains between these two divs , it takes 50/50 respectively of the opposite color to each div overflown.

I have no problem to change state according to the colors , but I can not make a smooth transition of color , instead of a sudden.

Here is the demo :

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(".menu").offset().top);
    console.log($(".blue").offset().top - 30);

    if ($(".menu").offset().top < ($(".blue").offset().top - 100)) {
        $(".menu").css("top", "30px");
        $(".menu").css("background-color", "#34495e");
    } else {
        $(".menu").css("background-color", "#ecf0f1");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.white {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.blue {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #34495e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers and tips.

I add a picture for help :
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/383878example.jpg

Comment: I am not fully sure if what you need is a `transition`. If you add `transition:all 0.5s;` to the CSS for `.menu`, does it behave in the way that you are looking for? Or what you want is to have half of the box in one color and the other call on the other?

Comment: Not quite , it's a nice option, but I really wish that as far as the box down into the div , it fills a contrasting color , not affecting the rest of the box is left on the first part.

n the case of using a transition, if the scroll is not performed fast enough, the box become , in this case white , and only be visible according to its half position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a gradient background for your menu div?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var menu = $(".menu");
    var blue = $(".blue");
    var gradient;
    var line;
    console.log(menu.offset().top);
    console.log(blue.offset().top - 30);

    if (menu.offset().top < (blue.offset().top) - 100) {
        menu.css("top", "30px");
        menu.css("background", "#34495e");
    } else if (menu.offset().top < blue.offset().top) {
        line = blue.offset().top - menu.offset().top;
        gradient = "linear-gradient(to bottom, #34495e " + line + "px,#ecf0f1 " + line + "px)";
        menu.css("background", gradient);
    } else {
        menu.css("background", "#ecf0f1");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49xhszhx/

Comment: Brilliant solution ! it is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Oh, you totally beat me to the answer haha.  Going to upvote and remove mine. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: 
add a transition time to background-color, 
and one intermediary color when the menu is half between.
as here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cosmycx/szyb384a/)

CSS:

```
transition: background-color 1s;
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
console.log($(".menu").offset().top);
console.log($(".blue").offset().top - 30);

if ($(".menu").offset().top < ($(".blue").offset().top - 100)) {
    $(".menu").css("top", "30px");
    $(".menu").css("background-color", "#34495e");
} else if ($(".menu").offset().top < ($(".blue").offset().top - 50)){
    $(".menu").css("background-color", "#6C7E8F");
    }
else{
    $(".menu").css("background-color", "#ecf0f1");
}
```

});